# "How to Fix:TypeError __init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_value' relating to Progress Bar

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I am currently attempting to train a model for speech recognition using mozilla deepspeech. This has been done on linux. Never had an issue with MacOs but having problems now.

I have tired setting up my virtual environment twice to solve this issue but it still is present. As stated above, I have tried this on MacOs but on linux i appear to have an issue. Could it be that python dependencies are installed differently on linux as opposed to mac?

````
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-train-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-train-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-train-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-train-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-train-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
/home/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-train-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-train-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-train-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-train-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-train-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/chabani/tmp/deepspeech-train-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorboard/compat/tensorflow_stub/dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
Loading TSV file:  /media/sf_en/train.tsv
Saving new DeepSpeech-formatted CSV file to:  /media/sf_en/clips/train.csv
Importing mp3 files...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/import_cv2.py", line 166, in <module>
    _preprocess_data(PARAMS.tsv_dir, AUDIO_DIR, label_filter_fun, PARAMS.space_after_every_character)
  File "bin/import_cv2.py", line 43, in _preprocess_data
    _maybe_convert_set(input_tsv, audio_dir, label_filter, space_after_every_character)
  File "bin/import_cv2.py", line 100, in _maybe_convert_set
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=num_samples, widgets=SIMPLE_BAR)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_value```

I expected that the data to train the model would import appropriately but it appears to not do so due to an incompatible progress bar.
````

Comment: Are you entirely sure that you have the correct dependencies installed? There are two "progressbar" modules that behave quite differently. `progressbar` hasn't been updated for a while, but `progressbar2` seems to be actively worked on. Could you verify that the exact same package is installed in both environments?

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you very much @HampusLarsson. It worked

Answer (score 9):

You've probably installed [progressbar](https://pypi.org/project/progressbar/) in GNU/Linux (`pip install progressbar`) instead of [progressbar2](https://pypi.org/project/progressbar2/) (`pip install progressbar2`).

The former accepts [maxval](https://github.com/niltonvolpato/python-progressbar/blob/master/progressbar/progressbar.py), while progressbar2 deals with needed [max_value](https://github.com/WoLpH/python-progressbar/blob/develop/progressbar/bar.py).

Comment: Thank you very much, @ipaleka. The suggestion worked.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using progressbar instead of progressbar2

- **Note**: In progressbar2 "**maxval**" was deprecated, so, now we should use
  **max_value**
- You must run your code in python3.7 environment to avoid error
  So, uninstall previous progressbar from your system using
  pip3 uninstall progressbar
  then install progressbar2 by
  pip3 install progressbar2
  if you are linux user 
  use 
  sudo pip3 install progressbar2
- run your python file in cmd or command shell as 
  **- python3.7 your_file_name.py**

Comment: Thank you, the issue was solved with the suggested approach

Answer (score 0):

By pass the dependency of Progress Bar.

Models are required to use [rembg](https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg/) library. It should be save under `~\.u2net` directory.

Follow the [documentation](https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg/#models) to download the model, in this case is 'u2net.onnx'.

Then try to rerun the scripts.

Alternative is to comment progressbar argument from the source, navigate to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\rembg\sessions\u2net.py`.

```py
pooch.retrieve(
            "https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg/releases/download/v0.0.0/u2net.onnx",
            None
            if cls.checksum_disabled(*args, **kwargs)
            else "md5:60024c5c889badc19c04ad937298a77b",
            fname=fname,
            path=cls.u2net_home(*args, **kwargs),
            # progressbar=True,
        )
```